# restrict child div height to parent container height

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, grid

I want the **graph** div to have a height that stretches all the way to the end of it's parent (**graph-container**) container, but not extend past it. I have tried setting **graph's** height to both 100% and inherit, but both of them result in it extending past it's parent container's bottom edge (I don't want to use overflow: hidden). Is there a way to set the height property on **graph** so it automatically sets its height to the right value?

Current output:[image: output]

What I want: [image]

Current code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.graph-container {
  border: 3px solid black;
  height: 60vh;
  width: 70vw;
  margin-top: 10vh;
}

.graph {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="graph-container">
        <h1>Graph Container</h1>
        <div class="graph">Graph</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The overflow you see happens because there is already an element taking up *some* space of the parent, so `height: 100%` plus the height of the other element will obviously exceed the parents height.

There are different ways to solve the problem.
I recommend one of these two ways:

- [CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
- [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

However, you can also solve them using these ways:

- CSS [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc())
- JavaScript

## CSS Flexbox

The parent needs `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` to lay out its children in a column.

The child that should grow to take up the remaining space needs `flex-grow: 1`.

```css
/* Ignore; only for displaying the example */
* {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 24px;
}
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.graph-container, .graph {
  border: 3px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* The answer */
.graph-container {
  height: 60vh;
  width: 70vw;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column; /* Shorthand for ('flex-direction' | 'flex-wrap') */
}
.graph {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="graph-container">
  <h1>Graph Container</h1>
  <div class="graph">Graph</div>
</div>
```

## CSS Grid

The parent needs `display: grid` and `grid-template-rows: auto 1fr`.

`grid-template-rows: auto 1fr` makes the second child take up the remaining space that is left over after the other children get their respective space that is defined without the `fr`-unit.
Here, `<h1>` gets its space it requires, and all the remaining space is given to `.graph`.

```css
/* Ignore; only for displaying the example */
* {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 24px;
}
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.graph-container, .graph {
  border: 3px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* The answer */
.graph-container {
  height: 60vh;
  width: 70vw;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
}
.graph {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="graph-container">
  <h1>Graph Container</h1>
  <div class="graph">Graph</div>
</div>
```

## CSS `calc()`

### Relation of `font-size` to `height`

As with the [solution of sergey kuznetsov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65194885/13561410), you can guess that `height` is (for small sizes only!) equal to `font-size`.

This is not always true, because `height` actually depends on `line-height`, which again depends on the font currently used.

#### The problem, illustrated

Say for example, that `line-height` is about `1.05`-times taller than `font-size` for a given font. Since the browser just can't display less than a `px`-unit, the decimal places are effectively cut off.

That makes the equation only true for small values of `font-size`, as can be seen in the examples below.
Examples (where `toInt()` cuts off the decimal places):

- `toInt(20px of 'font-size' * 1.05) = 20px of 'height'`
- `toInt(60px of 'font-size' * 1.05) = 63px of 'height'`

This means, while this works (for small `font-size`-values):
`calc(100% - 20px - 3px)` (`20px` due to `font-size`, `3px` due to `border-width`)

```css
/* Ignore; only for displaying the example */
* {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 24px;
}
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.graph-container, .graph {
  border: 3px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* The answer */
.graph-container {
  height: 60vh;
  width: 70vw;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.graph {
  height: calc(100% - 20px - 3px);
  display: block;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="graph-container">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <div class="graph">Graph</div>
</div>
```

... this won't work (for great `font-size`-values):
`calc(100% - 60px - 3px)` (`60px` due to `font-size`, `3px` due to `border-width`)

```css
/* Ignore; only for displaying the example */
* {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 24px;
}
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.graph-container, .graph {
  border: 3px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* The answer */
.graph-container {
  height: 60vh;
  width: 70vw;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
}
.graph {
  height: calc(100% - 60px - 3px);
  display: block;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="graph-container">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <div class="graph">Graph</div>
</div>
```

That is why it is best to actually define the `height`-property itself instead of relying on `font-size` or `line-height` to be the same as `height` (which it apparently isn't always). Which brings us to...

### Using CSS custom properties

You set the height of the second child to the remaining space with `calc(100% - TITLE_HEIGHT)` where `TITLE_HEIGHT` is the height of the other child, `<h1>`.

We can use [CSS Custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Variables) to set the height to reduce the amount of "magic numbers", which makes refactoring the code later on easier, and perhaps already easier to read.
I used `--title-height` for the height.

Custom properties are only accessible in the element itself and its children, which means that we need to define it in their parent `.graph-container`.

Now we can use the value of `--title-height` by resolving it using `var()` like this:
`var(--title-height)`

```css
/* Ignore; only for displaying the example */
* {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 24px;
}
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.graph-container, .graph {
  border: 3px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* The answer */
.graph-container {
  --title-height: 26px;
  
  height: 60vh;
  width: 70vw;
  
  display: block;
}
h1 {
  height: var(--title-height);
}
.graph {
  height: calc(100% - var(--title-height));
  display: block;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="graph-container">
  <h1>Graph Container</h1>
  <div class="graph">Graph</div>
</div>
```

## JavaScript

When using JS, we need to set the parent's height as well as the height of the `<h1>`-element, and calculate the remaining height for `.graph`. The remaining height can be set as the `.graph`'s height using `Element.style.height`.

```js
/* The answer */
var container = document.querySelector('.graph-container');
var title = document.querySelector('h1');
var graph = document.querySelector('.graph');

var remainingHeight = container.clientHeight - title.clientHeight;
graph.style.height = remainingHeight + "px"; // Make sure it is of unit "px"
```

```css
/* Ignore; only for displaying the example */
* {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 24px;
}
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.graph-container, .graph {
  border: 3px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.graph-container {
  height: 60vh;
  width: 70vw;
}
.graph {
  border-color: red;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="graph-container">
  <h1>Graph Container</h1>
  <div class="graph">Graph</div>
</div>
```

The problem with this approach is, that the height will be fixed once found. That will make `.graph` not responsive. To achieve that `.graph` is responsive, we need to observe if the parent was resized using a [`ResizeObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver).

Every time the parent resizes, recalculate the size of `.graph`.

```js
/* The answer */
var container = document.querySelector('.graph-container');
var title = document.querySelector('h1');
var graph = document.querySelector('.graph');

new ResizeObserver(() => {
  graph.style.height = container.clientHeight - title.clientHeight + "px";
}).observe(container);
```

```css
/* Ignore; only for displaying the example */
* {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 24px;
}
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.graph-container, .graph {
  border: 3px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.graph-container {
  height: 60vh;
  width: 70vw;
}
.graph {
  border-color: red;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="graph-container">
  <h1>Graph Container</h1>
  <div class="graph">Graph</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I also want to suggest a solution using `calc()`. Namely:

```
height: calc(100% - 23px);
```

Where 23px is the `h1` tag (`font-size: 20px`) and the border `graph` class is 3 pixels (`border: 3px solid red`).

In this example, the height of the child div will fit neatly inside the parent div.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.graph-container {
  border: 3px solid black;
  height: 60vh;
  width: 70vw;
  margin-top: 10vh;
}

.graph {
  height: calc(100% - 23px);
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="graph-container">
        <h1>Graph Container</h1>
        <div class="graph">Graph</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that `font-size` isn't equal to `line-height`. For greater `font-size`s, the actual elements height will differ from it. The `line-height` is dependent on the Font used, and is (at least in chrome I think) by default about `1.027`-times larger than the `font-size`. However, The `height` cannot fractions of a pixel tall, so the decimal places are "cut off", making it seem like `20px of 'font-size' = 20px of 'height'` whilst it actually is `floor(20px of 'font-size' * 1.027) = 20px of 'height'` where `floor()` "cuts off" the decimal places.

Comment: @OskarGrosser, yes, I know that. In this case, the `line-height` is not applied, so I gave this solution.

Comment: Okay then yes, you are absolutely right, here it is a feasible solution to do this. It would be great however to at least mention that this might become a problem for greater font-sizes.

Comment: @OskarGrosser, thanks, but your solutions are the best! :)

Comment: I added a sub-section regarding our "discussion" in my answer. You can edit it in case you have something to add.